# Deleting rows based on date comparison

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm writing a SQL script to remove some rows from my table.

I need to remove the rows that have a certain type (easy), where the valuation timestamp is 16:00 on the current day when the create date is less than 4pm. Does that make sense?

```
delete from cfo_daily_trans_hist where dh_dd_type_id = 'valuation' --and dh_val_time_stamp is today at 16:00 where the dh_create_dt is today at a time earlier than 16:00
```

I just don't really know the syntax to do that exact date comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE [dbo].[cfo_daily_trans_hist]
WHERE [dh_dd_type_id] = 'valuation' 
AND [dh_val_time_stamp] = DATEADD(HH, 16, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))) -- is today at 16:00 
AND [the dh_create_dt] < DATEADD(HH, 16, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())))-- is today at a time earlier than 16:00
```

Comment: This won't only give me the 16:00 rows though right? Won't it also give me a row if it has like 16:30? We only want to remove them if it's 16:00 exact on the value_dt portion

Comment: I'm using [`AND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188372(v=SQL.100).aspx) in the `WHERE` clause, so the query will only delete rows that match all the conditions.

Comment: There is an additional criteria for dh_create_dt to be today before 16:00.  This query (as written) will allow dh_create_dt to be any value before 16:00 on any day prior to today.

Comment: Good point @GMastros, you'll need another predicate to restrict `[dh_create_dt]` to before 1600hrs _today_, as in your answer: `AND [dh_create_dt] >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
And dh_val_time_stamp = DateAdd(Hour, 16, DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0))
And dh_create_dt >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)
And dh_create_dt < DateAdd(Hour, 16, DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- =================
-- sample data
-- =================
declare @t table
(
    dh_val_time_stamp datetime,
    dh_create_dt datetime
)

declare @d datetime
set @d = cast(cast(cast(getdate() as float) as int) as datetime)

insert into @t values (dateadd(hh, 16, @d), dateadd(hh, 14, @d))
insert into @t values (dateadd(hh, 1, @d), dateadd(hh, 2, @d))


-- =================
-- solution
-- =================
select 
    *
from @t t1
cross apply
(
    select d = dateadd(hh, 16, cast(cast(cast(getdate() as float) as int) as datetime))
) t2
where dh_val_time_stamp = d
and dh_create_dt < d
```